# SonarQube API for Hotspots

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-api

I am trying to call the SonarQube API hotspot and am getting a `404` status code.  I've followed the internal web api and generated this `request` to get the `hotspot key`.  This would allow me to generate another request to get the hotspots for a particular project.

```
<baseurl>/api/hotspots/search?hotspots&component=projectKey
```

Any thoughts?